# Creating a class that inherits from matrix and table

Tags: r

I need to define the new class(extended matrix and table) class. So the standard methods for these classes are inherited (eg print). I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Microsoft R Client

```
setClass("tm", contains = c("table","matrix"))
a = new("tm",c(1,2,3,4),2,2)
print(a);
```

After compiling the code, it return an error: 
*C stack usage  1994880 is too close to the limit*

The result should look like this

```
    [,1] [,2]
[1,]  1    2 
[2,]  3    4
```

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to extend both `"table"` and `"matrix"`. If `tbl` is of class `"table"` then try `m <- as.matrix(tbl); str(m)` and see the class of the result `m`. There is no `as.matrix` method for the class, but there is a `as.data.frame` method for class `"table"`.

Comment: @rui-barradas There must be any possibility it's my homework project for studies [link](http://michal.ramsza.org/lectures/2_r_programming_advanced/proj1/project_1.html) Its polish website but you can use google translate to understand it

Comment: Do it the other way around: `setClass("ematrix", contains = c("matrix", "table"));a <- new("ematrix", matrix(1:4, 2))`.